# T-SQL Group by multiple batches of 2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

So the wonderful people here on stackoverflow helped me with a "find consecutive failures" type query. (Status =4 is a failure). I thought I had cracked the second part of my problem because my test case seems to work fine but whenever I run it on our test environment I get dodgy results, so I must be doing something wrong. The goal is to find X number of consecutive failures. So the below is set to find 2 consecutive failures. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
[InstructionId] INT,
[InstructionDetailId] INT,
[Sequence] INT,
[Status] INT
) 
INSERT INTO @t SELECT 222,111,1, 2
INSERT INTO @t SELECT 222,112,2,2
INSERT INTO @t SELECT 222,113,3,4
INSERT INTO @t SELECT 222,114,4,4
INSERT INTO @t SELECT 222,115,5,2
INSERT INTO @t SELECT 222,116,6,4
INSERT INTO @t SELECT 222,117,7,2
INSERT INTO @t SELECT 222,118,8,4
INSERT INTO @t SELECT 222,119,9,4
INSERT INTO @t SELECT 222,120,10,2
INSERT INTO @t SELECT 222,121,11,2
INSERT INTO @t SELECT 222,124,12,4
INSERT INTO @t SELECT 222,126,13,4
INSERT INTO @t SELECT 222,128,14,4

INSERT INTO @t SELECT 223,126,13,4
INSERT INTO @t SELECT 223,128,14,4
INSERT INTO @t SELECT 223,129,15,2
INSERT INTO @t SELECT 223,130,16,4

INSERT INTO @t SELECT 224,111,17,4
INSERT INTO @t SELECT 224,112,18,4

INSERT INTO @t SELECT 223,160,33,4
INSERT INTO @t SELECT 223,161,34,4
INSERT INTO @t SELECT 223,162,35,4
INSERT INTO @t SELECT 223,163,40,4


;with HardcoreCTE AS
(
 select t.*,
  t.[Sequence] - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.instructionId ORDER BY 
  t.InstructionDetailId) AS ItemCount
  from @t t outer apply
    ( select top (1) t1.*
      from @t t1
         where t1.InstructionId = t.InstructionId and
         t1.Sequence < t.Sequence
   order by t1.Sequence desc
 ) t1 outer apply
 ( select top (1) t2.*
   from @t t2
   where t2.InstructionId = t.InstructionId and
         t2.Sequence > t.Sequence
   order by t2.Sequence 
 ) t2
where t.status = 4 and (t.status = t1.status or t.status = t2.status)
)
,

HardCoreCTE2
 AS
 (
 select *, Count(1) OVER(PARTITION BY ItemCount) AS ItemCount2 from 
 HardcoreCTE
 )

 select * from HardCoreCTE2
 where ItemCount2 =2
```

So the above works brilliants to find results where there are specifically only 2 consecutive failures with these

results:

[image]

Now from the above results the only ones it finds are the records where there are **2** consecutive failures but whenever I convert the above to the actual test environment tables it doesn't seem to work.

Test Env Results: As you can see for the "InstructionId" of 2518380 it brought back one record and the for "InstructionId" 2614351. It's meant to bring back sets of 2 records.

[image]

Test Env Query: (Pretty much identical)

```
;with InitialDataCTE
AS
(
   SELECT Instruction.InstructionID,InstructionDetail.InstructionDetailID, 
   InstructionDetail.InstructionDetailStatusID AS [Status],
   InstructionDetail.Sequence
   FROM     Instruction INNER JOIN
              InstructionDetail ON Instruction.InstructionID = 
   InstructionDetail.InstructionID

              where InstructionDetailStatusID =4
              and InstructionDetail.PaymentDateOriginal between '2015-01-05' 
       AND '2018-09-08'
  ),
  HardCoreCTE
  AS
  (
select t.*,
t.Sequence - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.instructionId ORDER BY 
t.InstructionDetailId) AS ItemCount
from InitialDataCTE t outer apply
 ( select top (1) t1.*
   from InitialDataCTE t1
   where t1.InstructionId = t.InstructionID and
         t1.Sequence < t.Sequence
   order by t1.Sequence desc
 ) t1 outer apply
 ( select top (1) t2.*
   from InitialDataCTE t2
   where t2.InstructionId = t.InstructionId and
         t2.Sequence > t.Sequence
   order by t2.Sequence 
 ) t2
where t.Status = 4 and (t.Status = t1.Status or t.Status = t2.Status)
)
,
 HardCoreCTE2
 AS
 (
 select *, Count(1) OVER(PARTITION BY ItemCount) AS ItemCount2 from 
 HardCoreCTE
 )
 select * from HardCoreCTE2
 where ItemCount2 =2
 order by InstructionID, Sequence
```

Really appreciate if someone can tell me where I am going wrong, I've been messing around with variations of the Count(*) but nothing successful yet. Thanx alot

Comment: Yeah good stuff to vote down the question without a reason whoever that was, very professional

Comment: I think I sorted it out, the line "select *, Count(1) OVER(PARTITION BY ItemCount) AS ItemCount2 from 
 HardCoreCTE" I changed to "SELECT *, 
                COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY InstructionId, 
                                           ItemCount) AS ItemCount2
         FROM HardCoreCTE" I added InstructionId on the PARTITION. Seems to working now.

Answer (score 1):

I came to the next query:

```
with
  a as (
    select *,
      row_number() over(partition by InstructionId order by Sequence)-
      row_number() over(partition by InstructionId, [Status] order by Sequence) g
    from @t
  ),
  b as (
    select *,
      count(*) over(partition by InstructionId, [Status], g) c
    from a
    where [Status] = 4
  )
select *
from b
where c > 2
order by 1, 3;
```

For your test data, I got the following result:

```
InstructionId   InstructionDetailId Sequence    Status  g   c
222             224                 312         4       6   3
222             226                 413         4       6   3
222             228                 514         4       6   3
223             161                 84          4       2   3
223             162                 95          4       2   3
223             163                 140         4       2   3
```

You can test this query [here](http://rextester.com/edit/LVPT97354).

Comment: thanx for the assist dude but I think I solved the problem. Check my one comment above on the question

Comment: @jjay225 Great! I glad to hear it.